# How to list all tables that have a matching string in its name

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

In Oracle DB, how to list all tables that exist in a schema with the table names having a substring like Student? Say you have a list of tables like College_student, Student_Offer  or Student_Dept etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may query the `all_tables` table:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '%student%';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE owner = :owner
   AND upper(table_name) LIKE '%STUDENT%';
```

we upper the name first in the predicate because some people insist on case sensitive object names in Oracle.

I run this with STU vs STUDENT in the LIKE search and see these results -

[image]

And since you tagged SQL Developer - you can simply browse a schema using the connection tree and optionally add a filter on the name.

[image]